# How to handle form input from web with Unicode and/or emoji?

Tags: perl

I'm working on code that accepts input from a web-based form. In some fields (like first and last name), users may enter special characters like umlauts. In other fields, like textarea comments, they may enter umlauts or even emoji. The input needs to be handled as entered by the user. The input is saved to MySQL using DBI queries with placeholders.

Do I need to untaint all input used in queries? And if so, how is untaint performed when the data from users may contain special characters and emoji?

I can untaint using something like this command line test, but the umlauts and emoji are stripped out.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw(tainted);

my $v = shift || die 'nothing';

$v =~ /(([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]| )+)/;
$v = $1;

if (tainted($v)) {
  die 'input is tainted';
}

print "$v\n";
exit;
```

Edit

Based on further testing and the comments, I've come to the following conclusions:

If input will be used only as placeholder data in a query with `$dbh->bind_param`, untaint is not needed.

"Bind values are passed to the database separately from the SQL statement, so there's no need to 'wrap up' the value in SQL quoting rules."

Lastly, the handling of umlaut and emoji characters in my test **seems** to be correct. Output in the browser looks correct, and values in the database also look correct. I'm able to search using ascii terms and MySQL matches the appropriate umlaut characters, etc.

- CentOS 8
- Perl 5, version 26
- MySQL 8.0.17 (using `CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`)
- DBI->connect (using `mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1`)
- No `binmode` in used in Perl script
- HTML has `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>` section

The input is handled using:

```
use CGI;
use Encode qw(decode_utf8);
my $q = CGI->new;
my $v = Encode::decode_utf8($q->param('comment') || 0);
```

I mention all of these details because, even though it looks like everything is working correctly, I could still be doing something wrong.

Comment: Taint is a mechanism to try to prevent some code injection bugs. So are you asking how to avoid these kinds of bugs with SQL? Make sure to use `$dbh->quote` or placeholders (e.g. `INSERT ... VALUES (?,?,?)`) for user-provided values, and `$dbh->quote_identifier` for user-provided table and field names (which should be validated against a white list)

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use `$1` unless you first made sure the regex pattern matched.

Comment: Tip: `[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]| ` is weird way of writing `[a-za-Z0-9 ]`

Comment: If they entered an umlaut, that's probably how you spell their name. Don't try to fix their name for them.